# How to get sum of field values in stimulsoft report

Tags: stimulsoft

I used the following code to get the sum of the field values :

```
{cSum(DataDataSource1,DataSource1.Hour)}
```

It works correctly for the all of the pages except the last one. If my last page has one record it shows 0 for the sum of the record and it's value gets added to the previous page!!

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: What version of Stimulsoft assemblies do you use?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get the sum of whole report use following in a `ReporSummaryBand`:

```
{Sum(DataDataSource1,DataSource1.Hour)}
```

and for sum of each page use following in `PageFooterBand` or `GroupFooterBand`:

```
{cSum(DataDataSource1,DataSource1.Hour)}
```

and just do the following :

1) double click on Text field that contain your sum Formula

2)in left panel choose `Summary`

3) in right panel :

for Whole report sum choose `Report` radio button

for sum of each page choose `Page` radio button

4) be sure `Running Total` and `Condition` Not checked.

I hope this be helpful

Comment: @somayeh.yazdane ,  Please upload and send the link  of your report and a sample code that I can get output report, so  I will try to solve it.

Comment: try tick ```running total```